# Is this question acceptable to migrate here?

Tags: support, migration

I'm a moderator on software quality assurance (sqa.stackexchange) and we had a post that came to the board over there.

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2390/tree-structure-for-android-open-source-project-source-code#question

Would this be something that's on topic for this site? Or would it just get closed anyway... If it's just going to be closed, I'll save you the trouble and close it on sqa. But if it's going to contribute to the community here, I'll migrate it over.

Comment: I would say StackOverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely not. That's a programming question, and programming questions go on Stack Overflow.